# How to display mongoose records in html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, promise, fetch

I am a newbie when it comes to Javascript, nodejs and all that, so please bear with me.
My goal is to set up a webpage, that displays a bunch of buttons. One button for example is called POST and does what it says. It sends information from the webpage to nodejs and finally Mongoose.
That is working. In the second step, I want to display exactly that record in HTML. That's not working for me.
However, my browser shows me the object in the response tab.

I use NodeJS, Javascript, Promises (async/await), HTML (no views).

Controller

```
const addBook = async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const addedBook = await Book.create({...req.body});
        res.status(200).json(addedBook)
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Client-Side JS:

```
const btn_POSTDOM = document.getElementById("btn_POST");
btn_POSTDOM.addEventListener("click", addBook);

async function addBook(e){
    try {
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = await fetch(baseURL, {
            method:"POST",
            headers:{"Content-Type":"application/JSON"},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                bookTitle : bookTitleIDDOM.value,
                publishDate: publishDateIDDOM.value,
                author: authorIDDOM.value
            })
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

[image]

I receive all sorts of promises, object object and such, but never the actual value in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to fix here.

Firstly, your `Book.create({...req.body});` is **not** working. You are creating a document in your collection yes, but the properties have no values e.g `bookTitle`, `publishDate`, `author` are all empty or `null`. You cannot use [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) because `req.body` is an object and spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function which objects don't have.

Secondly, you need the `req.body` to be parsed in your controller. This can be done by adding the following to your main server/index/app.js or whatever file your app is initialised in:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true} ));
app.use(express.json());
```

Now when you post to your `addBook` controller just destructure your `req.body` like so:

```
try {
   const {bookTitle, publishDate, author} = req.body;
   const addedBook = await Book.create({bookTitle, publishDate, author});
   res.status(200).json(addedBook)    
}
```

Lastly, in your `async function addBook(e)` client-side function you need to convert the response from `fetch` to a JSON, ready to work with. Update like so:

```
try {
   e.preventDefault();
   const data = await fetch(baseURL, {
      method:"POST",
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
         bookTitle : bookTitleIDDOM.value,
         publishDate: publishDateIDDOM.value,
         author: authorIDDOM.value
        })
    });
   const newBook = await data.json(); //< Add this
   console.log(newBook); //< See JSON in console
}
```

You will now be able to use the `newBook` JSON to loop through it and add DOM elements to your page until your heart's content.

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck with your project.